# display File Meta Data when I upload a phptp

Tags: file-uploads

If I upload a photo I fill out title, credit and description, but I can't find out how I can show this information on my site!

Answer (score 0):

Check the doc.. here https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/file.html. 
You need to use the tag pair.

Comment: Thanks for the solution